# Getting rows returned that don't conform to a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two types of rows in a table:

[image]

There is the standard data, which is tied to a taskId and is loaded into the database during a process, the first two rows below are this type of data. The second type of data is not loaded in the process, it is inserted as part of a form. YOu can see the difference because the first type of data has a taskId and NonScrumStoryId is NULL. In the second case, NonScrumStoryId column is populated and TaskId is NULL.

I have a query to get data from this table:

```
DECLARE @startDateParam DATETIME
    ,@endDateParam DATETIME
    ,@productId VARCHAR(100)
    ,@search VARCHAR(100)
    ,@userParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@orgTeamPK VARCHAR(100)

SET @startDateParam = '2013-11-25 00:00:00'
SET @endDateParam = '2013-12-01 23:59:59'
SET @productId = '%'
SET @search = '%%'
SET @userParam = '%'
SET @orgTeamPK = '%'

SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
        ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
        ,(
            CASE WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                        ) THEN 'KanBan' WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                        ) THEN 'Sprint' ELSE SCY.Catagory END
            ) AS ProjectType
        ,COALESCE(STY.[Number], NSS.IncidentNumber) AS StoryNumber
        ,COALESCE(STY.Title, NSS.[Description]) AS StoryTitle
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS Effort
        ,COALESCE(TSK.[Name], '') AS Task
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,SCY.Catagory AS Category
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber AS IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1 THEN DTH.[Hours] ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DTH.Hours > 0 THEN DTH.[UserDifference] END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DifferentUsers
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DTH.Hours > 0 THEN DTH.DoubleBookedFlag END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DoubleBookedFlag
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS PointPerson
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN SupportCatagory SCY ON NSS.CatagoryId = SCY.PK_SupportCatagory
    LEFT JOIN [Application] APP ON NSS.ApplicationId = APP.PK_Application
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON DTH.EnteredBy = USR.DisplayName
    WHERE DTH.EnteredBy LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
        AND (
            (
                @orgTeamPK = '%'
                AND (
                    USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                    OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @orgTeamPK <> '%'
                AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
                )
            AND (
                (
                    STY.Number LIKE @search
                    OR STY.Number IS NULL
                    )
                OR (
                    STY.Title LIKE @search
                    OR STY.Number IS NULL
                    )
                OR (
                    TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                    OR STY.Number IS NULL
                    )
                )
            )
    GROUP BY DTH.EnteredBy
        ,PDT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Description]
        ,STY.[Number]
        ,STY.Title
        ,TSK.[Name]
        ,SCY.Catagory
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName
        ,STY.KanBanProductId
        ,STY.SprintId
        ,NSS.[Description]
        ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
        ,STY.Effort
        ,DTH.PointPerson
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
```

My problem is that this query is only returning rows from the table that are from the process, it is not returning NonScrumStory columns and I need it to.

Edit: It appears part of the WHERE clause is causing the issue.

Ater investigation it probably has to do with this line:

```
AND PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
```

How can I remedy this?

Comment: I don't think it's your join that's causing the issue, it looks to me like it might be the `WHERE` clause. The `LEFT JOIN` you're using should do exactly what you want - rows that either match a TaskId or are null. If you remove your `WHERE` clause does it return all rows?

Comment: Yes, you are correct it appears to be the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're joining `Task` using

```
LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
```

then joining `Story` using

```
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
```

then joining `Product` using

```
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
```

(Note the Task -> Story -> Product reliance)

Those joins are all fine, but you're filtering on `Product` using

```
AND PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
```

This will, no matter what, match rows that have a product like the parameter which in turn limits the results to rows that have stories, which limits to rows that have tasks.

You can check if `@productId` is null or equal to the product. This will allow you to return all rows if the parameter is not specified, or return rows filtered to the product.

```
...
AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
AND (@productId IS NULL OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId)
AND (
...
```

If you need to always filter on product, then you'll probably have to use a `UNION` and select all rows with tasks in one, then all rows with `NonScrumStory` in the other.

Comment: Or instead of adding the `AND (... OR ...)` filter to the `WHERE` clause, just add the `AND ... LIKE` filter to the join criteria.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It was my assumption that adding that to the JOIN criteria would hurt performance more than checking `@productId IS NULL` in the `WHERE`... I've always found that multiple criteria in a `JOIN` slows queries way down.

Comment: I think you should not make too many assumptions and actually look and see how SQL Server evaluates the two queries. Besides, even if it did make a difference, do you think it will be a performance tipper for an aggregate query that does a LEFT JOIN against ~10 tables? This is like worrying about whether the piece of bird poop on my hood is going to wreck my gas mileage.